# Mobile User-Agent on IIS 7 windows 2008 r2 fails

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having a strange issue..I have a web (asp.net) application running on .net 2.0 framework. I was on windows server 2003, and I have just moved it on windows 2008 r2 64 bit.
Since it is moved to win2k8, mobile devices(mostly iPhones) can not not access the application. The only way iphone can access is if we change the user-agent string to desktop. On android tablet though (User-agent string=tablet not mobile) it works fine.

What is extremely baffling is that I have a vmware instance of the same server, I installed this web app there but have no such issue, on windows 7, no issue, I have another test machine with similar env win2k8 r2 64, and it shows no such problem...BUT only on this production machine where I am getting this annoying problem...does any one know some setting in IIS which could be causing the application to not create a session with mobile user-agent string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in case some one else comes across similar issue
I have finally figured out why this behaviour on one machine and not on others..it was freaking hellish to find out but I did.

This problem is introduced with the installation of Windows Server 2008 r2 SP1 . I can reproduce the issue at will, if remove SP1, all works as it did before and as soon as I re-install SP1 I get this error.

I have always known the part of the application which was redirecting, but my issue was that why this redirect had no bearing on all other instances and on this one it did.

It seems obvious that with SP1 some .net code has either started to work which was not working before(completely or partially).

the problem code for SP1 was where application determines if request was coming from a mobile device...in SP1 for win 2008 r2, it would throw exception